# Download file from google cloud storage using ruby client gets HTTP redirect

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am trying to download a file from GCS using the Ruby client and Service Account authorization; here is my code:

```
def build_client
  client = Google::APIClient.new()
  key = Google::APIClient::PKCS12.load_key(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, 'notasecret')
  service_account = Google::APIClient::JWTAsserter.new(
      SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control',
  key)
  client.authorization = service_account.authorize
  client
end

client = build_client
storage = client.discovered_api('storage', 'v1beta2')

#Get (download) a specific object from a bucket
bucket_get_result = client.execute(
    api_method: storage.objects.get,
    parameters: {bucket: BUCKET, object: params[:file_name], alt: 'media'}
)
puts bucket_get_result.body
```

The result body is a redirect detail as follows:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Temporary Redirect</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Temporary Redirect</H1>
The document has moved <A     HREF="https://storage.googleapis.com/my_bucket_name/my_file_name">here</A>.
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

...and then if I try to go to the redirect 'location' I get an Unauthorized HTTP. So, how can I download a file from GCS using the ruby client? https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get says:

> If you provide the URL parameter alt=media, then it will respond with the object data in the response body

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Google Ruby API client does not currently support downloading media.

However, you could always do the rest of the work yourself.

```rb
require 'httparty'

get_result = bucket_get_result = client.execute(
    api_method: storage.objects.get,
    parameters: {bucket: BUCKET, object: params[:file_name], :alt=>'media'})
url = get_result.response.env[:response_headers]['location']
token = "Bearer #{bucket_get_result.request.authorization.access_token}"
puts HTTParty.get(url, :headers => {"Authorization" => token}).body
```